# getPrice() fatal error in magento customs product

Tags: magento-1.7, product, price

when i tried to get the price attribute for the customs product type fatal error is displaying

```
$_product->getPrice();

Fatal error: Call to a member function getPrice() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/SVE279/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php on line 211
```

when it checked in the core file i found this

```
public function getPriceModel()
{
return Mage::getSingleton(‘catalog/product_type’)->priceFactory($this->getTypeId());
}
```

so the problem is with our customs product type any solution or fix for this problem

Comment: It's failing because $_product is NULL instead of an object. Check where you're assigning $_product.

Comment: Please post more code in the first block like the source of `$_product` (where it is assigned)

Answer (score 2):

Template contents are executed after their corresponding block class instance has been instantiated and prepared by the layout object. You should debug the following:

1. Which block class is being used
2. Which method is supposed to provide the product instance to `$_product` e.g. `$_product = $this->getProduct()` (or if a helper is being used, etc.)
3. Why #2 isn't working

Comment: hi ben i got other values using but i don't get price ,this problem happens only for custom product type with price model